# smarty for loop

Tags: php, smarty

By default using this code:

```
$value = check_input($_POST['num']);
If (isset($value) && !empty($_POST['numserials']))
        {
            for ($a = 1; $a <= $value; $a++)
            {
                $number = hash('tiger128,3',mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999));
                while (file_exists(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $number))
                {
                    $number = mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999);
                }
                file_put_contents(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $number,'');
                echo $number . '<br>';
                //$smarty->assign('number', $number);
            }
        }
```

In templated tried foreach, but no luck...
For example, echo give's everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$value = check_input($_POST['num']);
$numbers = array();
If (isset($value) && !empty($_POST['numserials']))
    {
        for ($a = 1; $a <= $value; $a++)
        {
            $number = hash('tiger128,3',mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999));
            while (file_exists(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $number))
            {
                $number = mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999);
            }
            file_put_contents(ROOT . '/intl/codes/' . $number,'');
            $numbers[] = $number;
        }
        $smarty->assign('numbers', $numbers);
    }
```

in your template file:

```
{foreach $numbers as $number}
{$number}<br />
{/foreach}
```